# How to best pass data for form editing in swuiftui (while having that data available to parent view and other subviews)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI form in a MyFormSubView.swift where I have multiple @State variables representing individual fields like Text, etc. My issue is my parent view "ContentView.swift" also needs access to this information, and other subviews "OtherView.swift" also would benefit from access for display or editing. My current approach, is to change all the @State to @Binding, which creates a headache because some forms could have up to 20 fields with some optional... what is the best way to handle this? Is there a way to simply pass an object and have that be 'editable'?

Approaches:

1. (Current, problem approach) Have multiple individual variables declared as @State
   in the ContentView.swift, and pass each individual variable into
   MyFormSubView.swift with those variables having @Binding in front of
   them that are mapped to swiftui elements to show up as 'placeholder
   text' in textboxes, etc. This is bad as I have potentially up to 30 fields with some being optional.
2. (What I Think I Desire) Have identifiable model with all the
   fields (and maybe pass this model into the MyFormSubView.swift, and
   if it's possible, bind to it and just have it such that each field
   is $mymodel.field1, $mymodel.field2, etc... which eliminates the
   need to have 30+ variables passed into this thing.
3. (Maybe Better?) Use an @ObservableObject.

Is #2 possible? Or is there an even better way? Sample code would be great!

Comment: Rolando, you can create a struct that you make a State object #2. You can then pass a single object to from your form.  Making it an observable object #3 would be even better. I will try and write it today post something later.

Comment: Rolando, posted an article on medium.com with all the options. Read it here. https://medium.com/codestory/a-real-world-challenge-passing-data-between-swiftui-views-51a52ba88dae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to pass data like this across Views. Here is a quick implementation outlining 4 approaches.

1. You can use an `@ObservableObject` to reference a class with all of your data inside. The variables are `@Published`, which allows the View to update in the same way a `@State` variable would.
2. You can use an `@StateObject`. This is the same as `@ObservableObject`, except it will only initialize once and if the view re-renders the variable will persist (whereas an `@ObservedObject` would reinitialize). [Read more about the difference here.](https://www.donnywals.com/whats-the-difference-between-stateobject-and-observedobject/)
3. You can use an `@EnvironmentObject`. This is the same as `@ObservedObject`, except it is stored in the Environment, so you don't have to manually pass it between views. This is best when you have a complex view hierarchy and not every view needs a reference to the data.
4. You can create a custom Model and use a `@State` variable.

All of these methods work, but based on your description, I'd say the 2nd method is probably best for your situation.

```
class DataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text1: String = "One"
    @Published var text2: String = "Two"
    @Published var text3: String = "Three"
}

struct DataModel {
    var text1: String = "Uno"
    var text2: String = "Dos"
    var text3: String = "Tres"
}

struct AppView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
            .environmentObject(DataViewModel())
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    
    @StateObject var dataStateViewModel = DataViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var dataObservedViewModel = DataViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var dataEnvironmentViewModel: DataViewModel
    @State var dataStateModel = DataModel()
    
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State var showOtherView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Text(dataStateViewModel.text1)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Text(dataObservedViewModel.text2)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            
            Text(dataEnvironmentViewModel.text3)
                .foregroundColor(.green)

            Text(dataStateModel.text1)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)

            Button(action: {
                showSheet.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Button 1")
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                FormView(dataStateViewModel: dataStateViewModel, dataObservedViewModel: dataObservedViewModel, dataStateModel: $dataStateModel)
                    .environmentObject(dataEnvironmentViewModel) // Sheet is a new environment
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                showOtherView.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Button 2")
            })
            
            if showOtherView {
                ThirdView(dataStateViewModel: dataStateViewModel, dataObservedViewModel: dataObservedViewModel, dataStateModel: $dataStateModel)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct FormView: View {
    @StateObject var dataStateViewModel: DataViewModel
    @ObservedObject var dataObservedViewModel: DataViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var dataEnvironmentViewModel: DataViewModel
    @Binding var dataStateModel: DataModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Form(content: {
            Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("BACK")
            })
            Text("EDIT TEXT FIELDS:")

            TextField("Placeholder 1", text: $dataStateViewModel.text1)
                .foregroundColor(.red)

            TextField("Placeholder 2", text: $dataObservedViewModel.text2)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)

            TextField("Placeholder 3", text: $dataEnvironmentViewModel.text3)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            
            TextField("Placeholder 4", text: $dataStateModel.text1)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
        })
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @StateObject var dataStateViewModel: DataViewModel
    @ObservedObject var dataObservedViewModel: DataViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var dataEnvironmentViewModel: DataViewModel
    @Binding var dataStateModel: DataModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text(dataStateViewModel.text1)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Text(dataObservedViewModel.text2)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            
            Text(dataEnvironmentViewModel.text3)
                .foregroundColor(.green)

            Text(dataStateModel.text1)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really useful, but how does one deal with one element of the OP's question: "...with some being optional"?

Answer (score 0):

Use ObservalbeObject, here is simple example how you can share data:
Step 1 - Add some kind of state:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: String = ""
}
```

Step 2 - Pass state to ContentView via setting enviromentObject

```
    ContentView()
            .environmentObject(AppState())
```

Step 3 - Now AppState will be available in all child views of ContentView, so here is the code for ContentView and OtherView. OtherView has the TextField, text from will be saved to AppState and you can be able to see it, when you press 'back' from OtherView.

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Content View")
                        .padding()

                NavigationLink(
                        destination: OtherView()
                ) {
                    Text("Open other view")
                }

                Text("Value from other view: \(appState.value)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OtherView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OtherView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    @State var value: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Other View")
                    .padding()

            TextField("Enter value", text: Binding<String>(
                    get: { self.value },
                    set: {
                        self.value = $0
                        appState.value = $0
                    }
            ))
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

This is just simple example, for more complex cases you can take a look on VIPER or MVVM patterns in Swift UI. For example, here:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/8440907-getting-started-with-the-viper-architecture-pattern
https://www.raywenderlich.com/4161005-mvvm-with-combine-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: Is it 'good practice' to maintain a single Observable+EnvironmentObject 'appState' that maintains any variables for the entire app? I know it is possible to have multiple ObservableObjects, but is it best practice to just have one?

Comment: It depends on how do you handle data and UI changes, what parts of UI should change, what shouldn't etc. For small apps with simple UI and examples - why not. For complex apps, there are many other patterns. For example each small module of an app can have it own 'state'.