# Should I use a Environment, State or Observed object to handle data array that uses json for persistence?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

Recently I have been running into bugs because of the way my app is structured so im making an attempt to improve how the app handles data, however I can't decide what to do.

Currently my ContentView (the root view of the app) owns the data array that is decoded from a json file using the following global function.

```swift
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {

    let readURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json")!
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent(filename)
        .appendingPathExtension("json")

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: jsonURL.path) {
        try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: readURL, to: jsonURL)
    }
    return try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(contentsOf: jsonURL))
}
```

The view loads this data like this:
`@State var bookData: [Book] = load("list")`

All other views use Bindings to edit this array and then the array is written using this global function:

```swift
func writeJSON(_ bookData: [Book]) {
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory
        .appendingPathComponent("list")
        .appendingPathExtension("json")
    try? JSONEncoder().encode(bookData).write(to: jsonURL, options: .atomic)
}
```

This method makes things difficult as as I go deeper into a navigation stack I end up binding to a binding to a binding to the original State var.

Rather than all of this, I was thinking I would create one array that all views could read and edit directly. From my research it seemed that an EnviromentObject would be my best bet however I found articles and questions that make seem to say anyone of the three would work.

Is the there any reason I may use one over the other, keeping in mind my use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the question is more about architecture pattern than about just what to use @State, @StateObject or @ObservableObject. You need to separate logic between several layers - view layer, data layer, service layer. Because what I see now is the root view is directly loading data to the view variable. In my opinion the best way is to choose most suitable for your case architecture pattern and refactor the code.

If you need the quick solution you can create a kind of observable 'state' for your app, pass it to ContentView as an @EvironmentalObject and it will be available for all child views. I've already wrote the quick example here: [How to best pass data for form editing in swuiftui (while having that data available to parent view and other subviews)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757784/how-to-best-pass-data-for-form-editing-in-swuiftui-while-having-that-data-avail/65758434#65758434).

Comment: Okay, the quick solution is something I can implement but im not realistically in a rush. Would the architecture mean something like mvvm (I keep seeing that on reddit). And specific resources or patterns you recommend?

Comment: The most popular with SwiftUI are MVVM, VIPER (or just it parts), Clean Architecture, you can find a lot of info about these three. VIPER: https://www.raywenderlich.com/8440907-getting-started-with-the-viper-architecture-pattern. Clean Architecture: https://nalexn.github.io/clean-architecture-swiftui/. In my apps I'm using Redux pattern with SwiftUI, but it came from the frontend and not too much info about how to use it with SwiftUI.